# Python Script in a Win BAT File Ignores raw_input()

Tags: python, windows, prompt

I am trying to launch a python script from a windows batch file, but when the program runs it ignores `raw_input()` and just continues.
I have tried both call and start, but to no avail.

The program should halt and prompt the input. However, running the same program from the cmd line works.

Comment: did you redirect standard input? can you show us a [mcve] ?

Comment: you are not showing your batchfile, so you will get downvotes.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard The problem was not related to the batch script.

Comment: Well, any code for that matter, you posted nothing.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Development is not exclusively about code and neither is StackOverflow. ["...the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It's not the best question by these standards, but I don't see that it's bad. This was a "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development".

Comment: You asked about a problem in why your code is not working, so yes, code is 100% relevant here.. Your own answer pointed out what you fixed in your code.

Answer (score -1):

When inspecting the error I realized that it was a path related import error, which suggests to me that the `sys.path` was initialized differently and did not include parallel directories.

After the `import sys` statement I simply included `sys.path.append('../')`.

Comment: Something is wrong if the script needs the parent directory of the process *working directory* added to `sys.path`. Plus, you're not resolving it to an absolute path, so the import path will change whenever the current working directory changes.

Comment: It would be a security hole if Python added the working directory (or its parent) to `sys.path` for normal script execution. All required modules and packages should either be in the script directory (including packages in subdirectories) or installed in site-packages or user site-packages, or in directories added by .pth files or `PYTHONPATH` -- all carefully controlled.